# Create Zip File with multiple files C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip, memorystream

I'm creating a Zip file from files I'm downloading from the internet in bytes[],
but I have an Issue, I don't know what I'm doing wrong... I generate the zip file but it's corrupted, the file size is correct(is not 0).
Could you help me please?
Maybe I didn't understand it well.

```
public <ActionResult> SomeFunction()
{
    var invoices = GetInvoices();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] zipBytes = null;

    using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            foreach (var invoice in invoices)
            {
                // This has correct values.
                byte[] fileBytes = client.DownloadData(invoice.XmlUri);

                // Create the instance of the file.
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(invoice.XmlFileName);

                // Get the stream of the file.
                using (var entryStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))

                // Get the Stream of the zipEntry
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                {
                    // Adding the file to the zip file.
                    entryStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }
        }
        zipBytes = compressedFileStream.ToArray();
    }
    return File(zipBytes , System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test.zip");
}
```

Comment: please try to close zipEntryStream with  `zipEntryStream.Close();`

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
zipBytes = compressedFileStream.ToArray();
```

To after the archive has been disposed so that all data is flushed to the underlying stream.

```
public <ActionResult> SomeFunction() {
    var invoices = GetInvoices();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] zipBytes = null;

    using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true)) {
            foreach (var invoice in invoices) {
                // This has correct values.
                byte[] fileBytes = client.DownloadData(invoice.XmlUri);

                // Create the instance of the file.
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(invoice.XmlFileName);

                // Get the stream of the file.
                using (var entryStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))

                // Get the Stream of the zipEntry
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                    // Adding the file to the zip file.
                    entryStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }            
        }
        zipBytes = compressedFileStream.ToArray();
    }
    return File(zipBytes , System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test.zip");
}
```

> **Reference [ZipArchive.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158289(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)**
>
> This method finishes writing the archive and releases all resources used by the ZipArchive object.
>   Unless you construct the object by using the [`ZipArchive(Stream, ZipArchiveMode, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137431(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor overload and set its `leaveOpen` parameter to `true`, all underlying streams are closed and no longer available for subsequent write operations.
>
> When you are finished using this instance of `ZipArchive`, call `Dispose()` to release all resources used by this instance. You should eliminate further references to this `ZipArchive` instance so that the garbage collector can reclaim the memory of the instance instead of keeping it alive for finalization.